# Вставка данных из списка python в таблицу документа WORD

Tags: python, django, list, ms-word, python-docx

У меня есть два списка :

```
['2021-04-30', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-06']

[1500, 450, 750, 900]
```

Есть шаблон документа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне вставить данные из списка date в {{date}} и данные из списка price в переменную {{price}}? В этом случае каждая новая запись в таблице должна начинаться с новой ячейки

Это работает, когда данные не являются списком

```
doc = Document('Шаблон.docx')
    date = post_data.get('date', False)
    price = post_data.get('price', False)
    context = {'date': date, 'price': price}
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save('restyled.docx')
```